# 8 Queen Puzzle with Reduced Ordered Binary Decision Diagram

Tags: binary-decision-diagram

I can not figure out how to solve the 8 queen puzzle problem with Reduced Ordered Binary Decision Diagram (ROBDD). I have googled it but can not find out good explanation of the problem. 
So, the problems here-
So far , I have figured out that there will be n*n input variable or state of the ROBDD. Now, how can I actually create a ROBDD that will solve the 8 queen puzzle ?

1. How ROBDD can find the solution in this problem ?
2. I can not figure out the graphical representation of the above problem
3. How actually does it produce minimum number of nodes ?
4. What about the ordering of the input variable ?
5. How it is reduced ?

Explanation will help me better understand the problem.

Comment: Regarding #3, what are those nodes and why do you want minimal number of them?

Comment: As this is the Compact BDD that means reduced and ordered binary decision diagram. @max

Comment: So, is your question about how to use BDD to solve 8 Queen puzzle or about how BDDs work in general?

Comment: @amee so which is it? Also I'm not convinced this is a good idea, N-Queens is a very "non-local" problem (effects can be felt arbitrarily far away from their cause), that tends to make BDDs explode in size.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit misleading. ROBDDs are only a mean to represent and manipulate Boolean functions. So, first of all, you have to work on a Boolean function that represent the problem. There is a lot of material on the n-queen problem, so I will not explain that in this answer.

Once you have your function, you can represent it on a ROBDD. Each node will probably answer the question “there is a queen in this square? YES NO”. Regarding reduce and reordering, there is not a direct connection with the problem itself. Reduce is a standard algorithm, and there are a lot of different algorithms and heuristics for reordering (for example the  CUDD package provide a dozen of them). Again, explaining those things in details is not the scope of this answer, and again there is a ton of material to look into on the internet. However, I can tell that the reduce algorithm will keep all the variables, since hardly you can have a situation where having or not a queen on a square is the same.

Now it’s time to look for the solution. If the problem actually has a solution, you will find at least one path that leads to the 1. Following that path (or those paths, there can be more than one), you can tell which variables are set to 1 or to 0 (that is, where the queens are located and where not).

Answer (score 1):

A formulation of the 8 queens problem in propositional logic can be found in Andersen's excellent [“An introduction to binary decision diagrams”, Lecture notes, TU Denmark, 1997](http://www.cs.unb.ca/~gdueck/courses/cs4835/bdd97.pdf).

I would recommend first writing such a Boolean formula yourself, then checking with that text to correct any mistakes, and so learn from them.

As for the list of questions: reading Andersen's introduction will answer Q2-5. These are questions on how BDDs work, not on the specific problem.

Q1: If the problem is to decide satisfiability (perhaps to enumerate the solutions as well), then it is the *construction* of a reduced BDD that solves the problem. By the canonicity of representation induced by variable ordering, the resulting BDD represents the set of satisfying assignments. That set is empty, if, and only if, the BDD is the terminal node "False".

Comment: An example of the N queens problem is at: https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/examples/queens.py