# Looking for applications of BDDs to problems involving x,y concept

Tags: linear-programming, coordinate-systems, binary-decision-diagram

I am looking at the [applications of BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) to figure out if it's possible to implement the x,y concept there.

Let me explain.

Let's say I have z of something to distribute in an x,y coordinate plane. The constraints are:

- All the z items have to be placed in the x,y coordinate plane.
- Some of the z items have to be a certain distance away from each other.

I think integer linear programming can sort this out. For example, with a set of equations, I can represent the constraints above and do linear programming to solve for the exact locations.

But what I am asking is if BDD can help with this?

In other words, can Binary Decision Diagram represent x,y coordinates and can I represent the above constraints with Boolean functions (equivalent to the set of equations above) and BDDs be manipulated to sort out the above constraints for exact locations just like linear programming?

I do not have any concrete examples to show but I think representing x,y coordinates equivalent in Binary is a place to start?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description and a detailed example of the problem/input you have. Also it is not clear how BDD is placed into this and how you want to come from a boolean function in BDD to coordinates on a plane.

Comment: My apologies. I do not have any specific examples in mind. I edited the question nevertheless. All I am asking is (I think) if there's a way for n bit strings (0,0,0,0) to correspond to an x,y coordinate plane?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: BDDs are quite efficient to solve 8 queen puzzle problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489260/8-queen-puzzle-with-reduced-ordered-binary-decision-diagram ). Maybe you get some idea there. The Andersen's paper, you should read, is mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed to know. May I also ask more about the second bullet point in the question, if I want to play with distance i.e. the inter-distance of z items, can the boolean expression capture that? Personally I don't think so just wanted to listen to more experienced person like you.

Comment: @meolic I have updated the title. Please let me know of the question above if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to encode the given integer-valued problem of placement over a plane using binary decision diagrams, and thus compute answers (as satisfying assignments). For example, using the Python package [`omega`](https://pypi.org/project/omega/) (which uses the Python package [`dd`](https://pypi.org/project/dd/) for BDD computations):

```py
from omega.symbolic import fol

fol = _fol.Context()
# Register integer-valued variables, with ranges of representation using BDDs
fol.declare(x1=(0, 11), y1=(0, 11), x2=(0, 11), y2=(0, 11))
# Encode the problem:
#
# Two points on a Euclidean plane are represented by their Cartesian coordinates
# `x1, y1` and `x2, y2`.
# Each point is in the square mesh `x \in 1..10 /\ y \in 1..10`.
#
# Note that the variables are declared with larger domains,
# in order to ensure that this boundary constraint is representable with the
# resulting BDDs.
#
# The distance between the two points should be the square root of 10.
expr = r'''
       (x1 >= 1) /\ (x1 <= 10)
    /\ (x2 >= 1) /\ (x2 <= 10)
    /\ (y1 >= 1) /\ (y1 <= 10)
    /\ (y2 >= 1) /\ (y1 <= 10)
    /\ (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) = 10
    '''
# Solve the problem, by adding creating a BDD for it
u = fol.add_expr(expr)
# Enumerate all solutions (i.e., all satisfying assignments)
# These are all the pairs of points within the box mesh x \in 1..10 /\ y \in 1..10
# that have a distance equal to the square root of 10.
assignments = list(fol.pick_iter(u))
print(assignments)
```

Using BDDs with distance constraints as above can lead to BDDs that are exponential in size in the number of variables. The reason is that representing multiplication can lead to exponentially-sized BDDs, as proved in https://doi.org/10.1109/12.73590 .

If the constraints are not distance between points, but distance along each axis (i.e., an inequality or equality constraint on the absolute value of `x1 - x2` or `y1 - y2`, or on both), then exponential complexity is avoided.

The above solves the placement problem over a mesh. This is a discrete placement problem. The continuous placement problem cannot be solved with binary decision diagrams, because it requires floating-point arithmetic.

The program above prints:

```py
[{'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 4, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 2, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 3, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 5, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 7, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 6, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 8, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 10, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 9, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 1, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 3, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 6, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 5, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 7, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 8},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 12},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 4},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 5, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 2},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 9, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 3, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 6},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 7, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 10},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 1},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 2, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 5},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 9},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 13},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 8, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 11},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 6, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 3},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 8, 'y2': 7},
 {'x1': 9, 'y1': 10, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 7}]
```

Comment: Thanks. How am I fulfilling the first bullet point i.e., all z items will be placed in the plane?

Comment: There are two items, one with coordinates `x1`, `y1`, and another with coordinates `x2`, `y2`. By definition, these two items are in a ([Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space)) plane.